# How to denote index set of a sequence minus 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Let $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ represent the entire indexed sequence $X$ where $I$ is the index set. I'm trying to represent value-to-value percent change of $X$. The denotation will be something like: $O = ((|(X_n - X_{n+1})|/X_n)*100)_{n\in I}$. When coding, you it would suffice to iterate up until the second to last value for this, since we are calculating the percent change between each value and the next. The last value has no subsequent "next" value, so it would throw an index error if you iterate all the way through. When representing this mathematically, though, does that matter or is the technicality implied? Should I use a different index set that is equal to $I$ all the way through the second to last value or does it not matter?

Comment: Perhaps
$$ \mathbf O = \left(100\frac{|\mathbf X(n) - \mathbf X(n+1) |}{\mathbf X(n)}\right)_{n,n+1\in \mathbf I}$$
its a little unclear but might get the message across

Comment: Why not be explicit about the size of your index set and write $[0,N]$ instead of $I$? Then you can write $n \in [0, N-1]$ for your sequence of changes.